# How to add page list in asp.net core MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to add page list in asp.net core MVC application so only 10 result will appear in the first page, to see more result I wanna add next option .I searched  but didn't found any solution for this operation.
There is NuGet package for asp.net but not for  asp.net core application.

[PagedList](https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList)

[X.PagedList](https://github.com/kpi-ua/X.PagedList)  (This is forked from PageList)

Comment: Pretty much any client-side component for this functionality (probably including what you linked to, or at least very closely) is going to have some means of performing an AJAX request to get its data, so as long as your application responds to that request then it should work fine.  The server-side technology used doesn't really change that.  What have you tried and where are you stuck?  If you're just looking for a plugin/tool recommendation then that's off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://github.com/kpi-ua/X.PagedList#about-net-core-support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd rather not use jQuery and a bunch of UI-layer scripts that users will be able to read, you can modify your controller and actions to use pagination.

See the link below for a tutorial on adding Sorting, Filtering and Paging to a list view.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page

I'm using this in a company project, and while it can be a bit cumbersome at first, once you get the hang of it it's easy to replicate the functionality in other pages.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery datatable plugin to show data. On pagination button click make ajax call to server method to retrive next data. You can use datatable server side by setting server attribute to true.
Please refer below links.

https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1011531/Using-jQuery-DataTables-with-Server-Side-Processin